# How to run docker image with specific version and port forwarding

Tags: docker

I want to run official Cassandra version 2.1.9 inside docker.
Also, I want to have following ports mapping:

```
7000:7000  
7001:7001  
7199:7199  
9042:9042  
9160:9160
```

What command do I have to run in order to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [official Cassandra image](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/cassandra/) doesn't have 2.1.9. The closest is 2.1.15 which shouldn't have any compatibility issues. The easiest way to run it is:

```
docker run -d -p 7000:7000 -p 7001:7001 -p 7199:7199 -p 9042:9042 -p 9160:9160 cassandra:2.1.15
```

`-p` publishes a ports from the image to a specific port number on the host. The [Cassandra Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/ef57ef961003e27469b86178f0b4d184bb64d82e/2.1/Dockerfile) exposes exactly those ports. You'd probably want to give the container a `--name` as well.

If you really want 2.1.9 you'll have to hunt for a non-official image or build your own.